# Why won't the shuffle function work in a PHP class?

Tags: php, oop, function, shuffle

Why won't it shuffle the array so I get a random result each time?

```
class greeting {
public $greet = array('hi','hello');
shuffle($greet);
}
$hi = new greeting;
echo $hi->greet[1];
```

Is their something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change it so the shuffle is inside the constructor it should work fine.

```
class greeting {

  public $greet = array('hi','hello');

  function __construct(){
    shuffle($this->greet);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also note that it may still not *look* like it's shuffling, even after being put in the constructor, but it is. It's just because you only have 2 items in the array, and they are getting shuffled into the same original order.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, an explanation would help me understand better as to why it's done that way.

Comment: @Matthew code being executed in classes must reside within a method. `__construct` is the name of the method that gets called when the object is created. For more information, I'd recommend checking out the PHP manual section on OOP :)

Answer (score 1):

any calculation can not be executed outside the method, inside class.

```
class greeting {
   public $greet = array('hi','hello');
   function __construct()
   {
     shuffle($this->greet);
   }
}

$hi = new greeting;
echo $hi->greet[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a class block you can only define constants, properties (both with fixed values) and methods. You can't put code in that block, code can only be placed inside methods (AKA functions).

Comment: Why can't code be placed in that block? Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: Because a class definition is not supposed to run code, its job is to define its components. Code is run within methods, if you need some code to be run when an object is created, put it in the constructor as @laurencek suggested.